# Sails.js - async controller fails to bind to routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Before Node.js 7.0 was released my Sails.js controllers looked something similar to:

```
const _async = require('asyncawait/async');
const _await = require('asyncawait/await');

...

get: _async (function (req, res) {
    try {
        let item = _await (Items.find({
            id: req.params.id
        }));
        if (!item.length) {
            return res.notFound("The item does not exist");
        }
        return res.ok(item[0]);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.serverError(error);
    }
}),
```

Everything used to run perfectly. After the release of Node.js 7.0, I changed it to:

```
 get: async function (req, res) {
    try {
        let item = await Items.find({
            id: req.params.id
        });
        if (!item.length) {
            return res.notFound("The item does not exist");
        }
        return res.ok(item[0]);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.serverError(error);
    }
},
```

But it logs error:

```
error: In items.get, ignored invalid attempt to bind route to a 
non-function controller: { [Function: get] _middlewareType: 'ACTION: 
items/get' } for path:  /v1/items/:id and verb: get
```

**Edit:**
Looks like a bug in underscore lib used by sails:

```
if ( !_.isFunction(originalFn) ) {
        sails.after('lifted', function () {
          sails.log.error(
            'In '+controllerId + '.' + actionId+', ignored invalid attempt to bind route to a non-function controller:',
            originalFn, 'for path: ', path, verb ? ('and verb: ' + verb) : '');
        });
        return;
 }
```

Logged an issue: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3863

Comment: And what does the route in your routes file look like for this controller?

Comment: @Ryan Route looks like: 'get /v1/items/:id': 'ItemsController.get',